# Vue grouping items by key then charting similar keys in one chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have  an object with the following structure;

```
{
  SensorA: [
    { id: 122, valueA: 345, "x-axis": 123344 },
    { id: 123, valueA: 125, "x-axis": 123344 },
    { id: 123, valueA: 185, "x-axis": 123344 },
    { id: 121, valueA: 95, "x-axis": 121344 },
    { id: 121, valueA: 125, "x-axis": 123144 }
  ],
  SensorB: [
    { id: 222, valueB: 785, "x-axis": 122344 },
    { id: 223, valueB: 485, "x-axis": 123394 },
    { id: 221, valueB: 432, "x-axis": 123344 }
  ],
  SensorN: [
    { id: 782, valueN: 295, "x-axis": 123344 },
    { id: 786, valueN: 895, "x-axis": 133344 },
    { id: 782, valueN: 755, "x-axis": 122245 },
    { id: 786, valueN: 295, "x-axis": 128844 }
  ]
}
```

each array key has objects making it up with a similar object structure for each key say sensorB have valueB and so on . I would like to make a dynamic card that has a chart of similar keys, basically a card with a multiline chart of similar sensors. I see how it can happen but I have no idea how to structure the code and html.kindly anyone assist me here
The following image shows an illustration of the desired results

[image]

Comment: Hi, Please follow this link to see an example mock using draw.io [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZSSEnU9wMKmDP16CnRL-jzxmfB3VxbOB/view)

Comment: I have realized I used your answer to group the objects with similar keys to arrive at the sample I provided above, now I want to know how to gro through that object while putting the data in a dynamic card component and the manipulating the individual component data like putting it in a babe and also having a multiline chart for all the data that belongs to one grouping

Comment: I have added the image now, was not sure if I could do that here. Basically each key group  is in a card with a multiline chart of the data of objects in the value array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone facing such a problem, I first grouped the array into objects like how I posted in the question then got the keys and the values. since each key is indexed as the values, I loop through the keys in v-for and then pass the value index as that key to the component being iterated by the key as props

```
<div v-for="(sensor, index) in data.keys"
      :key="sensor.keys"
      class="q-pa-md col-xs-12 col-sm-6 "
    >
      <Chart :sensor="sensor" :arr="data.val[index]"></Chart>
    </div>
```